# Group array of hashes by key

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array consisting of hashes in the following form:

```
[
  {:user=>"mike" etc},
  {:user=>"mike" etc},
  {:user=>"peter" etc},
  {:user=>"joe" etc}
]
```

Are there any convenient ways to split the group according to the value of user key? The final result should be something like this:

```
[
  [{:user=>"mike" etc}, {:user=>"mike" etc}],
  [{:user=>"peter" etc}],
  [{:user=>"joe" etc}]
]
```

Comment: How do you get that data? From a database query? If so, you should do a  `group by` in your query rather than after the fact.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `group_by`.

```
array.group_by{|h| h[:user]}.values
```